# Emergency Boot Mode Error

Tags: boot, kernel, bootloader, systemd-journald, gnome-activity-journal

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS.

There are similar questions, but the poster was already much further along before posting and I don't know how to get to their initial step.

**What's happening?**

When I turn on my computer it boots to emergency mode. I was able to print the journal and have included photos further down.

There are options to go to recovery mode. When I'm in recovery mode I can't move down the menu, but am able to write into a command line.

**How did this happen?**

An external HD suddenly wouldn't mount. It's NTFS and I concluded there was some read/write issue. Therefore I found some code online. After entering this code I rebooted. This is when the issues started. My OS is on an internal drive and I'm fairly sure its file system is fuse.

This is the code I entered. The code executed.

```
sudo apt-get purge ntfsprogs 
sudo apt-get purge ntfs-3g 
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

**Examples of errors**

I've photographed some of the journal. If there's a better way please let me know.

- These are images of journal output that have coloured lines: https://postimg.cc/gallery/0mhcKJP
- And here are images of white-coloured lines of code: https://postimg.cc/gallery/z84GL6n

I don't understand how an NTFS.

EDIT 1:

It wouldn't let me boot into recovery mode unless the external HD was connected. Weird. As said previously my OS is on an internal.

EDIT 2:

Tried

```
fsck /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

Output was

```
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 is mounted.
e2fsck: cannot continue, aborting
```

EDIT 3:

Tried

```
fsck -nf /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

The output is here:
https://postimg.cc/Th9Hx2vM

I then tried to unmount the drive but it said 'target is busy.'

Comment: You have to run fsck from unmounted partitions. If partially booted, it will not work. If recovery mode, you can have it before mounted. Better to use live installer in live mode to run fsck on ext4 partitions. But if NTFS, you have to use Windows to make repairs. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred Thanks. I solved this by editing fstab and have included details in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from users in another forum.
Answer is here:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ubuntu-only-boots-to-emergency-mode-4175716928/

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer and add what exactly worked for you? As it currently is  it is just a link, so it would have no value if for some reason the link would break. Also, as a link-only answer, it is in danger of deletion, which would be bad for other users with the same problem as you. Also have a look at this post of the Help Center: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following code by replacing diskname with the partition in which your home is installed

```
$ fsck /dev/diskname
```

From your uploaded images `nvme0n1p2` is where your file systems likely exists so you could run;

```
$ fsck /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

Comment: It says it is mounted. e2fsck: cannot continue, aborting. @Arjun K Shibu

Comment: Try `fsck -nf /dev/nvme0n1p2`. If that doesn't work try `umount /dev/nvme0n1p2` followed by `fsck -nf /dev/nvme0n1p2`

Comment: `fsck -nf /dev/nvme0n1p2` produced this    https://postimg.cc/Th9Hx2vM .......I rebooted and it just hung on the loading screen ....I rebooted into recovery mode. It wouldn't go into recovery mode unless the external HD was plugged in. Which is weird. I then rebooted and try to mount and it said target is busy @Arjun K Shibu